# Hash speed attack

Tags: security

I'm discovering alt-coins.

Now, I'm on [piratecoin](https://cryptocointalk.com/topic/3054-piratecoin-ptc-information/).

```
{
    "blocks" : 34167,
    "currentblocksize" : 1225,
    "currentblocktx" : 1,
    "difficulty" : 0.14348426,
    "errors" : "",
    "generate" : true,
    "genproclimit" : -1,
    "hashespersec" : 355,
    "networkhashps" : 11127177,
    "pooledtx" : 1,
    "testnet" : false
}
```

There is somehow calculated `networkhashps`, seems it is aproximation from `difficulty`, it is 11,127,177, ~ 11mh/s. I'm count on my own, `350h/s`, however, `cgminer` show me `180Kh/s`. Probably it doesn't counts in `getmininginfo` or recalculated somehow. Anybody?

I've seen persons with much greater speed, its called mining rig. 20-30 may be 100 GPU in a bunch.

What if such huge miner connect to such young alt-coin network, download whole of current blockchain, and start mining off-line. After 5 hours he come back to network, his blockchain will be with bigger `difficulty`.

Can he attack network in such way?

Comment: Yes, read for example [CoinDesk: Feathercoin hit by massive attack](http://www.coindesk.com/feathercoin-hit-by-massive-attack/)

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. When a coin is secured by proof of work, if there is insufficient proof of work, the coin is not secure.

Comment: What kind of protection exist? I've heard about PoW, PoS, alphabet blizzard....